# Want to Tag a model package instead of model_package group with aws sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

{
"statusCode": 500,
"body": ""Failed to create model package: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModelPackage operation: Tags are not supported in Model Package versions. Please add them to the Model Package Group.""
}

Answer (score 2):

Tags are not supported on the Model Package. Tagging is supported only on the Model Package Group. Model Packages have an attribute called `CustomerMetadataProperties` which supports key, value pairs. You can use this to add information to your Model Package.